# How much does a tourist visa for Vietnam cost?

Tags: visas, vietnam, tourist-visas

The US Vietnamese embassy [website](http://vietnamembassy-usa.org/consular/visa-application-process) lists the requirements for the visa application, but does not list the fee for doing so (though it does say **how** to pay it). The only information on the page about the fee is:

> Fee for stamping visa can be checked at Consular Fee

What is the current fee for a tourist visa to Vietnam?

Comment: Realise this is an old question, but if the embassy in the US is anything like the UK one, then you have to email them for up to date prices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I asked the embassy and they got back to me, here is what it costs to go directly through the US embassy:

> From: Vietnam Consular [dcconsular@gmail.com]
>
> THE FOLLOWING FEE IS TOTAL FEE, COVERING FOR VISA STAMPING FEE, VISA
>   APPROVAL ARRANGEMENT FEE AND PROCESSING FEE.
>
> A. SINGLE ENTRY, ONE-MONTH:
>
> - $100.00/ EACH PERSON
>
> B. SINGLE ENTRY, THREE-MONTH: $140.00/ EACH PERSON
>
> C. MULTIPLE ENTRY ONE-MONTH: $150.00/ EACH PERSON
>
> D. MULTIPLE ENTRY THREE-MONTH: $180.00/ EACH PERSON

(their capitalization, not mine... eek.)

Answer (score 3):

From 29 August 2016, all visas will be issued in 1-year-visa multiple entry is granted for US citizens with maximum 90 days of stay per one entry to Vietnam.

The stamping fee at [Vietnam airport for US citizens](http://needvietnamvisa.blogspot.com) will be $135 USD

you can read here: http://tuoitrenews.vn/business/36900/vietnam-tourism-watchdog-decries-new-visa-fee-for-us-visitors

tuoitrenews.vn is the reputable newspaper in Vietnam

Comment: It sounds like you (like most of the other answers here) are talking about the pre-approved visa on arrival, and not the full visa from the embassy, which is what the question asks about.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a 45.00 USD stamping fee plus additional [fees](http://www.myvietnamvisa.com/vietnam-visa-cost.html) depending on how you process. Additionally, you will need two passport photos and one blank page for the visa and one page with enough space for the entry and exit stamps.

In the past I have used [this](http://www.myvietnamvisa.com/). It may a seem a bit shady from a Western perspective, but it works.

Comment: This applies to the "pre approved visa on arrival", not the visa acquired through the embassy.

Answer (score 1):

For [stamping fee](https://getvietnamvisa.com/pricing.html) you have to pay at the airports
1 or 3 month/single: US$ 45,
1 month/multi: US$ 65,
3 months/multi: US$ 95

You need only 1 photo and your passport must been over 6 months valid.
For service fee, you have to pay to travel company to apply approval letter for you from US$ 10 to 20, it is depend on the company.
You have to pay for visa is service fee + stamping fee.

Comment: This applies to the "pre approved visa on arrival", not the visa acquired through the embassy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your nationality (some may not need), visa type, how long you stay, normal processing or urgent processing... As I researched, there are two kinds of tourist visa for 1 and 3 months and you can apply also for single entry or multiple entry.

> Once arrived in Vietnam, tourists can also apply for Visa Extension of
>   Tourist Visa if they want to spend more time here. Stamping fee is the
>   fee you pay the Immigration Officers directly and in cash (USD or VND)
>   at your arrival airport in Vietnam (Immigration Desk/Counter) to have
>   Visa stamped onto your passport. The fee is collected by Immigration
>   Officers and compulsory for all those who use Visa on Arrival method.
>
> For 1 month single entry, stamping fee is $25/person
>
> For 1 month multiple entry, stamping fee is $50/person

The rate is displayed here ([Vietnam Visa Fee](https://www.bestpricevn.com/vietnam-visa/visa-fees.html)). Nowadays, it's easy to apply a Visa on Arrival online (You will need to pay extra service fee, for $2 to $7).

Comment: This answer is still talking about the pre-approved visa on arrival process, not the process involved in getting a visa direct from the embassy as the OP originally asked.